# Resizing a photo to a format compatible with Active Directory

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

I have a function to resize an image that I am receiving from an external system to then enter into Active Directory to meet the size restrictions, however it doesn't seem to work. When I resize the image using this code, it doesn't seem to be compatible and attempting to set the image generates errors.

If I open this image, it looks fine. If i then then save it with an image editor, I can then import it into AD, so it's definitely something about this function that isn't quite right, I think it's something encoding related, but I don't know quite enough to fix it.

I can load the photo (the original one that's too big for AD) using the following code:

```
$original = [system.io.file]::ReadAllBytes('C:\original.jpg')
```

I then resize it and attempt to add it to AD, which fails.

```
$scaled = ResizeImage -ImageData $original -Percentage 80
Set-ADUser user -Replace @{ thumbnailPhoto=$scaled }
```

This gives me errors from

> Set-ADUser : Multiple values were specified for an attribute that can have only one value

to

> Set-ADUser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

depending on how and where it's run. I've confirmed it's not permissions or connectivity related, as I can write other data and images not scaled through this process.

If i write the the $Scaled image to disk, i can then re-save it with an image editor which makes this work. Function is below, any help would be massively appreciated!

```
function ResizeImage {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [byte[]]
    $ImageData,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [double]
    $Percentage,

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('HighQuality', 'HighSpeed', 'Antialias', 'Default', 'None')]
    [string]
    $SmoothingMode = "Default",

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('Bicubic', 'Bilinear', 'HighQualityBicubic', 'HighQualityBilinear', 'Default', 'High', 'Low', 'NearestNeighbor')]
    [string]
    $InterpolationMode = "Default",

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('HighQuality', 'HighSpeed', 'Half', 'Default', 'None')]
    [string]
    $PixelOffsetMode = "Default"
)
Begin {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
}
Process {
    $ImageBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ImageData)
    $ImageMemory = [System.IO.MemoryStream][System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ImageBase64)
    $Bitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap][System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($ImageMemory)
    $Product = $Percentage / 100
    [int]$NewHeight = $Bitmap.Height * $Product
    [int]$NewWidth = $Bitmap.Width * $Product

    $NewMemory = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::New()
    $NewBitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::New($NewWidth, $NewHeight)
    $NewImage = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($NewBitmap)
    $NewImage.SmoothingMode = $SmoothingMode
    $NewImage.InterpolationMode = $InterpolationMode
    $NewImage.PixelOffsetMode = $PixelOffsetMode
    $NewImage.DrawImage($Bitmap, $(New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Rectangle -ArgumentList 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight))
    $NewBitmap.Save($NewMemory, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg)
    [byte[]]$NewMemory.ToArray()
}
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `Set-ADUser` argument: `@{ thumbnailPhoto=$scaled }` -> `@{ thumbnailPhoto=,$scaled }`

Comment: This gives me an `Set-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Object[]'.` error. I know the setting of the attribute is OK, since if I import an image without scaling it that part works, it's just the run through of the function that seems to change the encoding or the properties of the image in such a way that it's incompatible with AD (or the Set-Aduser function).

Comment: Then it's most likely just because of a type check, explicitly cast to `[byte[]]` and you should be good: `@{ thumbnailPhoto = [byte[]]$scaled }`

Comment: Thats crazy! it works in my test, i'll try it in my full test tomorrow and let you know. Do you know why that's needed to work even though i'm using [byte[]]$NewMemory.ToArray() to emit the object from the function? I can't see any difference in the object when piping both $scaled and [byte[]]$scaled to get-member.

Comment: This works over a wide range of images, thank you very much!